# Correct regex to allow spaces in phone number field

Tags: regex, wordpress

I'm currently using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/si-contact-form/ and have got a telephone field with the following regex:

```
(^\+?\d+$)
```

However I want to allow spaces. I don't really understand regex, but have tried:

```
(^\+?\d+\ $)

(^\+?\d+\ +$ )

(^\+?\d+\s+$ )
```

And can't seem to get any of them to work? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) ***[(demo)](https://regex101.com/r/oO5gF4/1)***:

```
^\+?[\d\s]+$
```

<sub>*the parenthesis are unnecessary*</sub>

---

Essentially, you were already using a character class. `\d` is a shorthand character class that (for all intents and purposes) is the same as `[0-9]`, or any character in the range 0-9. `\s`, as you seemed to know, is for whitespace. My answer, `[\d\s]`, makes a custom character class with both of those shorthand notations...so any character that is a digit or whitespace.

Comment: Brilliant thanks. Can you link me to somewhere that explains this in a bit more detail? Will mark as the answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: I just updated the "character class" text with a link: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: Yep have just seen it. Thanks bud.

Comment: Use of character class is right. But use of `\s` has to be checked. Because `\s` not only allows space but also other whitespaces which phone number cannot have.

Comment: `\h` can also be used, which is horizontal whitespace, or just a plain space (`[\d ]`).

Comment: I think the plain `\d` should suffice. The Phone number pattern also matters. Because Very few of them start with `0`. OP hasn't provided any Input or output so it's unclear.